# Nginx Configuration for Oracle Linux Server returning/redirecting to default oracle page

Tags: node.js, linux, oracle, nginx

[webpage screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQFsZ.png)

Nginx configuration:

```
server
{
    listen 80;

    server_name ****;

    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

}

server
{
    listen 443;

    server_name ****;

    location /
    {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;

        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}

server
{
    listen 443;

    server_name ****;
    
    location /
    {
        #root /var/www/tite_staging/public/www/;

        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;

        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

removed "return 302 https://$host$request_uri;" from http block because it causes a ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error

May I know what the issue is here? thank you.
Running a javascript application with node server

Answer (score 0):

```
server {
    listen       80;
    # catch all server names here
    server_name  _;

    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen       443;
    server_name  tite.rdc.nie.edu.sg;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}

server {
    listen       443;
    server_name  staging.tite.rdc.nie.edu.sg;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8088/;    # <--- SEE PORT HERE
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

Assumptions:

- URL *tite.rdc.nie.edu.sg* running application branch A on server A
- URL *staging.tite.rdc.nie.edu.sg* running application branch B on server A

Means that you can not run two different applications on same server behind same port. During application start-up you should get error message, something like:

```
Bind address already in use
```

Also check /etc/nginx/config folder if it does not contain another (defaults) *.conf files

Comment: Hi @Facty thank you for the help. It was serving wherever the root is defined in the main nginx config file (/etc/nginx/nginx.conf) because I did not define a root in the HTTP block. Using only the http block listening to port 80 (incl. root /var/www/....) did the trick